# Self terminating Self-hosted WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I have a console app which is self-hosting the ASP.Net WebAPI.  I would like the console app to self terminate based on a specific call to the WebAPI.

The console app is heavily based on the example found here -> http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api

To provide some context;

The console app will be used in conjunction with Jenkins CI to automate BDD testing of an Android application.  Jenkins will be responsible for building, installing and initiating an Android app - it will then invoke this console app.  The Android app will run through a series of Jasmine BDD tests automatically returning updates to Jenkins via the console app/ WebAPI.  On completion of the tests, the Android App will call a specific WebAPI action - at this point I want it to terminate the console app so that Jenkins will move onto the next build step.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx). In your Program class, add a static public field:

```
public static System.Threading.ManualResetEvent shutDown =
       new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

And then in your main method:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
{
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    //Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
    //Console.ReadLine();
    shutDown.WaitOne();
}
```

And then in the appropriate API method:

```
Program.shutDown.Set();
```

When your main method exits, the program will stop.

Comment: If this shutdown switch will be set in the API method, would it send correct response? It looks like the program will stop immediately  but what happen with all requests which are currently processing?

Comment: @eXist - shutting down processes whilst actually smoothly dealing with ongoing requests are why systems such as IIS exist. They deal with creating new processes to cater to new requests and not tearing down the old process until ongoing requests have been sorted. If you're going your own way, you have to build that infrastructure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To shutdown a normal .Net application you can use:

```
System.Environment.Exit(0)
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

Comment: This is, in my opinion, a last resort solution.  Damien's method will allow for cleaning up properly before exiting (shutting other threads cleanly, for example), whereas this solution is more of a Wail and Bail.